# Need help obfuscating Java SWT application

Tags: java, swt, proguard, obfuscation

I'm trying to obfuscate my Java SWT program with ProGuard.
It works, and when decompiled using jd-gui, the code seems to be all in place (Obfuscated).

However, when I try to start the program it crashes.
Console output:

```
#
# A fatal error has been detected by the Java Runtime Environment:
#
#  EXCEPTION_ACCESS_VIOLATION (0xc0000005) at pc=0x000000006324b7c0, pid=6944, tid=0x00000000000009e4
#
# JRE version: Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (8.0_144-b01) (build 1.8.0_144-b01)
# Java VM: Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (25.144-b01 mixed mode windows-amd64 compressed oops)
# Problematic frame:
# V  [jvm.dll+0x15b7c0]
#
# Failed to write core dump. Minidumps are not enabled by default on client versions of Windows
#
# An error report file with more information is saved as:
# Z:\Wouter\Code66\hs_err_pid6944.log
#
# If you would like to submit a bug report, please visit:
#   http://bugreport.java.com/bugreport/crash.jsp
#
```

The hs_err.log file: https://pastebin.com/gHm5rFgP

My ProGuard config:

```
-injars 'Z:\Wouter\Code66\Program 64bit.jar'
-outjars 'Z:\Wouter\Code66\Program 64bit obfuscated2.jar'

-libraryjars 'C:\Program Files\Java\jre1.8.0_144\lib\rt.jar'
-libraryjars 'Z:\Wouter\Code66\SWT libraries'
-libraryjars 'Z:\Wouter\Code66\javax stuff'

-dontshrink
-dontoptimize

-dontwarn org.**
-dontnote org.**

#-dontobfuscate

-dontusemixedcaseclassnames
-dontskipnonpubliclibraryclasses
-verbose

-keep class !my.package.**
-keep public class my.package.Main
-keep public class my.package.Main { 
      public static void main(java.lang.String[]); 
}
```

The program works just fine if I don't obfuscate the code, using `--dontobfuscate`

What should I do to fix this?